# Unable to pop item from stack

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I implemented a SLL with nodes that look like this

```
public class StudentNode<T>
{
    private StudentNode<T> next;
    private T std;

    public StudentNode(T s)
    {
        this.std=s;
        this.next=null;
    }

    public StudentNode()
    {
        this.std=null;
        this.next=null;
    }

    public T getStudent()
    {
        return this.std;    
    }

    public void setNext(StudentNode<T> ln)
    {
        this.next = ln;
    }

    public StudentNode<T> getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

I have to use the SLL to simulate a stack(lifo structure)

```
public class LinkedStack<T> {

  private int size;
  private StudentNode<T> head;
  /* methods */
  public boolean pop()  
  { 
    if (getSize()>1) {
      StudentNode<T> ss=this.head;
      for(StudentNode<T> sb=ss;sb!=null;sb=sb.getNext())
        System.out.println(((Student)sb.getStudent()).avg());//prints the grade
      while(ss.getNext().getNext()!=null){
        ss=ss.getNext();
      }     
      ss.setNext(null); 
      this.size-=1;
      for(StudentNode<T> sb=this.head;sb!=null;sb=sb.getNext())
        System.out.println(((Student)sb.getStudent()).avg()+"*");
      return true;
    }
    else
    if(getSize()==1){
      this.head=null;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have to pop out the last element of the list but it seems to make me a copy of it instead of cutting it off.What am I missing here?

First execution:

```
5.0
10.0
2.0
5.0
4.0
5.0*
10.0*
2.0*
5.0*
```

Second execution:

```
5.0
10.0
2.0
5.0
5.0
4.0
5.0*
10.0*
2.0*
5.0*
5.0*
```

Comment: How does the pop() method makes you a copy of the last element since it returns boolean?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Also unclear why you're looking 2 nodes ahead; seems like that's going to throw an NPE when size == 2.

Comment: @BrianRoach, I think when size is 2, the while is not executed and the link to the second element will be removed -> looks ok.

Comment: Impossible to tell without his code, yeah.

Comment: @wxys Kind of like this,I included some prints in the method and updated the question with the outputs

Comment: @BrianRoach Because I have to pop only the last element.That means I have to erase the pointer from the pre-last element and I can't go backwards on my list.

Comment: I copied your code, added push implementation and print method and tried pushing `{5, 10, 2, 5, 4}` and then popping. The result is `{5, 10, 2, 5}`. I think the error is somewhere else, in code you did not post.

Comment: Is anything happening between the runs or are you just doing `stack.pop(); stack.pop();`? Also, hen you pop the last element (size == 1) you do not update the size to 0;

Comment: @RogerLindsjö yes,just `pop()` everytime.I did it 10 times and the result is the same as the second execution

Comment: @Matt I can not reproduce that, I try adding 10 students and then do 10 pop and the output is as I would expect. When you say "second execution" what do you mean? Can you show your push method and also a simple example of adding and piping that shows this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your output seems correct to me. Given what I guess is the intention of your code: Removing the last element from the Linked List. If I reformat your output I get the following:

First execution

```
before  | after
5.0       5.0*
10.0      10.0*
2.0       2.0*
5.0       5.0*
4.0
```

Second execution

```
before   | after
5.0        5.0*
10.0       10.0*
2.0        2.0*
5.0        5.0*
5.0        5.0*
4.0
```

So, in both cases, the last element is removed. (By the way, you forgot to update the size in the elseif branch).

Second, the intention of pop on a stack is normally to remove the top element, i.e., the head. Not the bottom element as your implementation currently does. Considering this, your implementation boils down to:

```
public class LinkedStack<T> {

  private int size;
  private StudentNode<T> head;
  /* methods */
  public boolean pop()  
  { 
    if (this.size > 0) {
      this.head = this.head.getNext();
      this.size--;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```